# How to get the middle characters of string that is a Date and Time?

Tags: c#

Trying to get a character out of a string but it displays error

> "Index and length must refer to a location within the string"

here is my sample code below, the error part occurs in the "timeOnly"

```
string sampleDate = "2020-09-16T05:32:38+8:00";

        string dateOnly = sampleDate.Substring(0, 10).ToString();
        string timeOnly = sampleDate.Substring(12, 18).ToString();

        string finalDate = dateOnly + " " + timeOnly;
```

How do i get the time only of `sampleDate` and get only `05:32:38` out of the `string`

Comment: From [Tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging): _"The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title."_ _"Avoid inserting tags into titles in any of the following formats:"_ **_"[question title] in [tag]"_**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

only change the range, for example :

```
string timeOnly = sampleDate.Substring(11, 8).ToString();
```

result:05:32:38

Comment: Right, except it's 8, not 7.

Answer (score 6):

> How to get the MIDDLE characters of string?

In short, you don't

What you have is a `DateTime` not just a regular string. The most reliable and sane way to treat it is by parsing it as a `DateTime`, or `DateTimeOffset`. Since you don't want the timezone information you can use the later and format it however you like

```
string sampleDate = "2020-09-16T05:32:38+8:00";
var asd = DateTimeOffset.Parse(sampleDate);
Console.WriteLine(asd.TimeOfDay.ToString());
```

If you need the *Timezone* information in the future, you might want to use `DateTime.Parse`. This all gives you the ability to treat the *Date Time* / *Time* as such if and when you need it, with the standard formatting features and cultural tools needed when dealing with such constructs

**Output**

```
05:32:38
```

[Full Demo Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zmIzFr)

Comment: hi, the data being extracted is shown in that format, so i cant change the data tye

Comment: @JediAblaza there is no need to change the format, however it is wise to be parsing Date and time information not using string manipulation. It can cater for differing formats, cultural differences, timezone, and lots more

Answer (score 5):

The second parameter to the Substring method is the *length* you want, not the end index. And the first parameter is also wrong in your second call.

So, change to this:

```
string sampleDate = "2020-09-16T05:32:38+8:00";

string dateOnly = sampleDate.Substring(0, 10).ToString();
string timeOnly = sampleDate.Substring(11, 8).ToString();

string finalDate = dateOnly + " " + timeOnly;
```

A couple more tips. You don't need to write the variable type when it can be inferred. And Substring already returns a string, so no need to call ToString.

```
var sampleDateString = "2020-09-16T05:32:38+8:00";

var dateOnly = sampleDate.Substring(0, 10);
var timeOnly = sampleDate.Substring(11, 8);

var finalDate = dateOnly + " " + timeOnly;
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the reply but i forgot to mention that i also tried removing the "ToString();" and still get the same error

Comment: The `timeonly` shouldnt be `(12, 8)`, it should be `(11, 8)`

Comment: @JediAblaza Take a look at the first part of my answer. I was saying the number you pass to Substring is wrong. The part about removing ToString is an extra suggestion to make your code better, but not a fix for the problem you asked about.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ You're right. I didn't see that. I fixed it.